# Golang 1.5 io.Copy blocked with two TCPConn

Tags: tcp, go, connection

http://play.golang.org/p/gZo5RqgY4F

I have a question with `io.Copy` method. The link above will block in line 44 under Go 1.5. But will pass in 1.4.2. I have no idea with this issue.

Here is my go version: `go version go 1.5 darwin/amd64`.

When did the `io.Copy` return in go 1.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously, you were getting lucky when the timing of the syscalls would cause a write error in your second `io.Copy` [line 41]. (Ignoring errors tends to hide bugs)

This was purely by accident (and may even be incorrect). Since the source connection of that copy (`conn2`) is never closed, the `io.Copy` never receives an `io.EOF` and doesn't return. You need to close the opposing connection in each of the copy goroutines to unblock the other's call to `io.Copy`.

```
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    io.Copy(conn1, conn2)
    // conn2 has returned EOF or an error, so we need to shut down the
    // other half of the duplex copy.
    conn1.Close()
    wg.Done()
}()

wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    io.Copy(conn2, conn1)
    conn2.Close()
    wg.Done()
}()
```