# Correct usage of io.Copy to proxy data between two net.Conn TCP connections in Golang?

Tags: go, tcp

There are conflicting usages of `io.Copy` and I want to know the correct way to copy data between two TCP connections in Golang?

Some people say to call Close inside the goroutines, and others don't
[Golang 1.5 io.Copy blocked with two TCPConn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460618/golang-1-5-io-copy-blocked-with-two-tcpconn)
https://github.com/LiamHaworth/go-tproxy/blob/master/example/tproxy_example.go#L159

Here are the two common patterns I've seen online, both seemly work fine in my tests, but I'm worried about edge cases and I cannot figure out which, if any, is correct?

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net"
    "sync"
)

func proxy1(conn1, conn2 net.Conn) {
    defer conn1.Close()
    defer conn2.Close()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        io.Copy(conn1, conn2)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    go func() {
        io.Copy(conn2, conn1)
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}

func proxy2(conn1, conn2 net.Conn) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        io.Copy(conn1, conn2)
        wg.Done()
        conn1.Close()
    }()
    go func() {
        io.Copy(conn2, conn1)
        wg.Done()
        conn2.Close()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Proxy 1: The proxy deadlocks when a peer waits for EOF before the peer closes the connection.

Proxy 2: The proxy can close a connection before all data is read from the connection.

This code fixes both problems:

```
func proxy(conn1, conn2 *net.TCPConn) {
    defer conn1.Close()
    defer conn2.Close()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        io.Copy(conn1, conn2)
        // Signal peer that no more data is coming.
        conn1.CloseWrite()
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        io.Copy(conn2, conn1)
        // Signal peer that no more data is coming.
        conn2.CloseWrite()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```